# How to use Vue Router's lazy loading with vue-class-component?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-class-components

I'm still fairly new to Vue, and trying to implement lazy loaded routes on a project that uses class style components. Currently the components are defined for the routes using Webpack's dynamic import like so:

```js
{
  path: '/dashboard',
  name: 'dashboard',
  component: function() {
    return import(
      /* webpackChunkName: "dashboard" */ '../components/content-views/content-main/ContentDashboard.vue'
    );
  },
},
```

But this doesn't seem to be working, as loading the app with an empty cache downloads all of the chunks up front, resulting in an enormous app file. Reading the [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html#grouping-components-in-the-same-chunk), it looks like I need to define the class components as async by returning a Promise which resolves with the component. However, I'm honestly not sure if that's possible with a component which is a class definition, as opposed to a typical object-based one. The `vue-class-component` documentation doesn't mention this, but I'm wondering if there's some kind of alternative syntax for achieving this, or if I'm missing something else.

Any assistance appreciated!

Comment: How are you verifying that all the chunks are being downloaded up front? FYI, the `import` function returns a `Promise` so it's not something you need to worry about in your component

Comment: Looking at the network tab, basically every JS file for every route is being loaded.  I would assume that, using code splitting, if a component is only being rendered in the router for a specific route, simply navigating to the default route shouldn't load that component's code. In the app it's only being rendered by the ```router-view``` component.

Comment: The way you implement it seems correct. I have the behavior you described above with the same implementation. Did you check that the cross dependency of your components? say your Home component use ContentDashboard or it's child component?

Comment: Are you looking at a production build (ie not the Webpack Dev server)?

Answer (score -1):

This is how you can use lazy routing in vuejs

```
path: "/",
    name: "index",
    component: () =>
        import("../views/Index.vue")
```

Answer (score -1):

just as MaBbKhawaja said,

```
path: "/",
    name: "index",
    component: () =>
        import("../views/Index.vue")
```

you can also assign chunkName like this

```
path: "/",
    name: "index",
    component: () =>
        import(/* webpackChunkName: "Home" */ "../views/Index.vue")
```

[The docs gives a better explanation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html)